# Add TextBoxes Dynamically in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, textbox

I want to create TextBoxes dynamically in tabular format. So far i am successful of creating 10 textboxes in a vertical format. But i want to create 10X10 grid of textboxes. Here is the code. This code runs successfully but creates only 10 textboxes. I know there's a small mistake in code but i am not getting it. Please help

```
Dim XPos, YPos As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim j As Integer = 1
    Dim newBox As TextBox
    XPos = 20
    YPos = 30
    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 10
            newBox = New TextBox
            newBox.Name = "txtR" & i & "C" & j
            newBox.Size = New Drawing.Size(54, 22)
            newBox.Location = New Point(XPos, YPos)
            newBox.Text = newBox.Name
            Me.Controls.Add(newBox)
        Next
        YPos += 30
    Next
```

Comment: You're not incrementing `XPos` in your `j` loop, your textboxes are being created over the top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will help you

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim XPos, YPos As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim j As Integer = 1
    Dim newBox As TextBox
    XPos = 20
    YPos = 30
    For i = 1 To 10
        XPos = 20
        For j = 1 To 10
            newBox = New TextBox
            newBox.Name = "txtR" & i & "C" & j
            newBox.Size = New Drawing.Size(54, 22)
            newBox.Location = New Point(XPos, YPos)
            newBox.Text = newBox.Name
            Me.Controls.Add(newBox)
            XPos += newBox.Width + 5
        Next
        YPos += 30
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hello, add tasks **EXAMPLE**
Here this code to add the textbox in runtime to panel (container_control)
then move the scrollbar of the panel to the current and last textbox will add:

```
Dim txt As TextBox
Dim newLine As Integer = 50
Dim taskN As Integer = 1




Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point()

    txt = New TextBox()
    txt.Name = "note1"

    'txt.BringToFront()

    txt.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(111, newLine)
    txt.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(318, 68)
    txt.Text = "Task" + taskN.ToString()

    txt.Font = New Font("Verdana", 30, FontStyle.Regular)

    Panel1.Controls.Add(txt)

    Me.Text = Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.ToString()
    Label1.Text = txt.Location.ToString()

    newLine += 60
    taskN += 1
    'Me.SuspendLayout()

    Panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(txt)
```